# update select columns in select rows only from csv data

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I have a table with 7 columns and thousands of rows and I want to update a select few rows matching an id number (leaving the non matching rows alone) from records provided in csv file. The update provided has the matching record ID and only three of the matching columns.
I created a temporary table from the provided csv. In the temp table I made the matching id column (c1) the index, and c3 key. The content in c3 is text and it is stored with the asterisks.
I have tested a few dozen sql queries using methods of update, insert and join from reading here.
The closest I've come to a successful result had the major problem of updating the c1 and c3 fields in every row of the table (which previously had both unique and null content) with a duplicate content of "1" in c1 and "*option1*" in c3.  Here is how the tables/data are structured:

```
    TABLE 1 (T1)
    c1id, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
    1   a   null    05      red     medium  0.070
    2   b   null    02      Sydney  dark    0.000
    3   c   null    null    crystal null    null
    4   d   null    02      egg     dark    0.114
    5   e   null    03      hard    bright  0.000

    TABLE 2 (T2)
    c1id, c3, c4, c7
    1   *option1*   null    0.025   
    2   *option1*   02      0.000
    5   *option1*   09      0.751

    TABLE 1 Desired Result:
    c1id, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
    1   a   *option1*   null    red     medium  0.025
    2   b   *option1*   02      Sydney  dark    0.000
    3   c   null        null    crystal null    null
    4   d   null        02      egg     dark    0.114
    5   e   *option1*   09      hard    bright  0.751

    TABLE 1 ACTUAL Result:
    c1id, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7
    1   a   *option1*   05  red     medium  0.070
    1   b   *option1*   02  Sydney  dark    0.000
    1   0   *option1*   08  stone   dark    0.000
    1   d   *option1*   02  egg     dark    0.114
    1   e   *option1*   03  hard    bright  0.000
```

Here are some query attempts:

```
    update table1, table2 set
        table1.c1=table2.c1
        table1.c3=table2.c3
        table1.c4=table2.c4
        table1.c7=table2.c7
    where table1.c1=table2.c1 ;

    update table1 dest, table2 src set
        dest.c1=src.c1
        dest.c3=src.c3
        dest.c4=src.c4
        dest.c7=src.c7
    where dest.c1=src.c1 ;

    update table1 dest, (SELECT * FROM table1 where c3=*option1*) src 
    SET dest.c4 = src.c4 where dest.c3=*option1*;

    SELECT c1,
    c3,
    c4,
    c7
    FROM table2
    INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.c1 = table2.c2
    WHERE table1.c1 = table2.c1;
```

Comment: What environment is this in?

Comment: I am using sql via phpmyadmin.  I thought I had this licked by adding a where (between and ) on the destination primary, but it only updated 179 out of the 768 rows that should have updated which is baffling....

Comment: won't let me answer my own question but I figured it out.  I had done it before but transposed two of the numbers in the range which explains why only 179 had updated.  So here is the solution that worked for me:

        update table1 dest, table2 src set
                dest.c1=src.c1
                dest.c3=src.c3
                dest.c4=src.c4
                dest.c7=src.c7
        where (dest.c1=src.c1) and (dest.c1 BETWEEN 471954 AND 472722);